# Reordering the members of a vector based on a set pattern

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I have a std::vector of constant size 2n, and its contents - more vectors - are added in this order (cannot be changed):
1, 1+n, 2, 2+n, 3, 3+n, 4, 4+n etc.

For instance, where n=6 the order of adding would be: 1,7,2,8 etc.

Once populated, I would like to reorder the contents of my vector to 1, 2, 3 etc.

Can anyone suggest how I might go about that? I can't help thinking there's some lovely elegant approach that's just beyond my reach.

Comment: The entries themselves could be anything, so: Fred, John, Bill, Marcus, Dorothy, Hilda, Gavin, Greg, Wendy, Naomi, Sue and Nick would become Fred, Bill, Dorothy, Gavin, Wendy, Sue, John, Marcus, Hilda, Greg, Naomi, Nick.

Comment: You're looking for list slicing and striding. Boost range has it. Posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little help from my friends @Boost:

```
typedef std::vector<int> V;
V const v { 1, 9, 2, 10, 3, 11, 4, 12, 5, 13, 6, 14, 7, 15, 8, 16 };

auto rearranged = copy_range<V>(join(
       v | strided(2), 
       v | sliced(1, v.size()) | strided(2)));
```

See it **[Live At Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44a5a1b07411c0ad)**

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/join.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>

using namespace boost::adaptors;
using boost::copy_range;

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    typedef std::vector<int> V;
    V const v { 1, 9, 2, 10, 3, 11, 4, 12, 5, 13, 6, 14, 7, 15, 8, 16 };

    auto rearranged = copy_range<V>(join(
         v | strided(2), 
         v | sliced(1, v.size()) | strided(2)));

    // print the result
    boost::copy(rearranged, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,";"));
}
```

Prints

```
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the vector is of a constant size 2n, while populating you can change the index accordingly.

```
index = (i%2) ? i/2+n+1 : i/2+1;
```

Where `i = 0 to 2n-1`

When you get the value of n, declare your vector as

```
std::vector<myType> vec( 2*n );
```

Comment: Seems reasonable.  Do I need to do anything to the vector in advance?  When I said "set size", what I meant was "known at the time the class which holds the vector is instantiated".

Answer (score 0):

the function to map from current place to proper place is easy enough.

```
fn(int x,int n) { (i%2) ? i/2+n+1 : i/2+1; }
```

Declare a new vector, with default contents. The loop over them doing swaps.

```
for(i=0,i<size;i++) {swap(v1[i],v2[fn(i,n)]);}
```

Of course this likely has serious off by one issues, since your description is 1 based, not zero based like vectors.